# Unmarshal XML with no wrapper elements for repeating element to POJO using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am looking to unmarshal xml as shown below to POJO using JAXB. The confusion is that there is no wrapping element for sub elements. e.g.

```
<class>
   <studentId>1</studentId>
   <studentName>Mickey</studentName>
   <studentId>2</studentId>
   <studentId>Minnie</studentId>
</class>
```

I am relatively new with JAXB and I haven't faced this case earlier. The case where the xml is as below works correctly to get a StudentClass Object with List of Student objects.

```
<class>
   <student>
       <studentId>1</studentId>
       <studentName>Mickey</studentName>
   </student>
   <student>
       <studentId>2</studentId>
       <studentId>Minnie</studentId>
    </student>
</class>
```

Can anyone please point me to appropriate documentation or provide suggestions to handle the first case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to annotate your list of students field with `@XmlElement`:

```
@XmlElement(name="student")
```

also you can wrap you list of students with `<students></students>`:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="students")
```

The result will be:

```
<class>
   <students>
       <student>
           <studentId>1</studentId>
           <studentName>Mickey</studentName>
       </student>
       <student>
          <studentId>2</studentId>
          <studentId>Minnie</studentId>
       </student>
    </students>
</class>
```